# Subsetting of Lists in R

Tags: r, list, subset

I had a few questions about subsetting a named list in R using the `[]` operator:

For example, consider the list `formals <- list(x = DOUBLE, y = DOUBLE, z = NULL)`. In this example, `DOUBLE` is treated as a symbol in R.

1) How should I retrieve all elements that are not equal to `NULL`. I tried `formals[formals != NULL]` but this only returns an object of type `list`with no members.

2) How should I retrieve elements whose names satisfy for a condition. For example, how would I get all elements whose names are not `z`? I could use `names(formals)` but this is cumbersome and I was hoping for a quick solution using `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option for the first question:

```
Filter(Negate(is.null), formals)
```

For the second case, you'll have to use `names`. Here's one way:

```
formals[names(formals) != 'z']
```

`formals` is actually a function in R. It's best to avoid names of functions when naming your variables.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for your first question:

```
formals[!unlist(lapply(formals, is.null))]
```

I don't think you can avoid using `names` for the second question.